# Angular ng-repeat with custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, directive

I'm having difficulty with the data from my controller scope being passed into a custom directive. The ng-repeat give me the correct number of elements, it's just not loading in the template or something.

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('WorkflowController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.columns = ['Requested Quote', 'Quote Sent', 'Deposit Paid'];
}])
.directive('kanban-column', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {column: '='},
    templateUrl: 'directives/kanban-column/template.html'
  }
})

// template.html:
<h4>{{column}}}}</h4>
```

With this in my index.html:

```
<div class='kanban-board'>
    <kanban-column data-ng-repeat="column in columns" data-column="column">
    </kanban-column>
</div>
```

The code is simplified a bit for clarity, but even the above verbatim does not work. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: not work mean?? are you sure data returning from that??

Comment: what is in template.html?

Comment: template.html is just the <h4>{{column}}</h4>

Comment: And I am getting 3 'kanban-column' elements after the ng-repeat evaluates, but none of them are displaying the {{column}} data

Answer (score 4):

First of all you have not passed `dependency` in `your app` so it will never instantiate .

```
angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('WorkflowController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.columns = ['Requested Quote', 'Quote Sent', 'Deposit Paid'];
}]).directive('kanbanColumn', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {column: '='},
    template: '<h4>{{column}}</h4>'
  }
});
```

Try this one .

```
<div class='kanban-board'>
    <div data-ng-repeat="column in columns">
       <kanban-column data-column="column">
       </kanban-column>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Working plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/A31sKQoAgBTJBE9wVMZG?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

try this code

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.0.x" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.0.7"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="WorkflowController">
    <div class='kanban-board'>
      <kanban-column data-ng-repeat="column in columns" data-column="column">
      </kanban-column>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**JS:**

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('WorkflowController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.columns = ['Requested Quote', 'Quote Sent', 'Deposit Paid'];
  }])
  .directive('kanbanColumn', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      scope: {
        column: '=?'
      },
      templateUrl: 'template.html'
    };
  });

template.html:
<h4>{{column}}</h4>
```